# SolrCloud: is unique key really mandatory?

Tags: solr, cloud, unique-key

In a single node setup I had **auto-generated unique key** by using UUID:

```
<field name="my_id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NEW" />
```

Now I want to move to [**distributed Solr**](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud) setup, but when I add documents without `my_id` I get following error:

> Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: my_id

Does it mean that I need to generate unique key by myself outside of Solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in Solr 4.0 (or Solr Trunk).

There is a JIRA opened on it   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2796 .  The fix has yet to be committed.